# Upgraded to Rails 6.0 without webpacker | No scss / bootstrap in Heroku production

Tags: heroku, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-6

I tried upgrading my Rails app from 5.2.3 to 6.0 without Webpacker first.

Everything works fine locally and Heroku Staging, however, when deploying from Heroku Staging to Heroku Production, SCSS / Bootstrap is not loaded. Also, the rails version loading at production seems to be 4.1 rather than 4.0 as specified in gemfile.

What am I missing?

**Gemfile**

```
ruby '~> 2.6.6'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 4.0'
...
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.5.2'
...
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 2.2.0'
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require ahoy
//= require cocoon
//= require jstz
//= require_tree .
```

**production.rb**

```
    Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:email, :provider_address),
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:domain_name, :production),
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:email, :provider_username),
    password: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:email, :provider_password)
  }
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "www.#{Rails.application.credentials.dig(:domain_name, :production)}" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

end

Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:domain_name, :production)
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', async: true %>
```

**application.scss**

```
 @import "bootstrap";
 @import "**/*";
 @import "1st_load_framework";
 @import "fontawesome-all.min";
```